# Having Difficulty With This Q: Allow User To Input Values of Array and Do So With For, While loops, also output the largest number entered

Tags: c++, algorithm, loops, for-loop, max

I have to create a function which uses a for loop or while loop and an array, to display the largest number out of a group of numbers, and I'm having trouble with the question in the title.

When I run this code, it's not allowing the user to input however many elements in the array he wants, and it does not stop when the user wants to stop by entering a letter like g  for ex.  It also doesn't output the largest number at the end of what the user wants entered in the array.

What exactly is wrong with my code?

```
   #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;

   void printarray(int array[], int size)
   {
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    cout << array[i] << endl;
}

return;
   }

    int main()
    {
   const int SIZE = 2000;
   int count = 0;
   int userinput[SIZE];
   int largest = 0;


for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    if (cin >> userinput[i])
    {
        count++;

    }   
    else
    {
        break;
    }

    while (count < userinput[i])
    {
        if (largest < userinput[i])
        {
            largest = userinput[i];
        }

        count++;                

                 }}

       printarray(userinput, count);

       cin.clear();
       cin.ignore();

       return 0;
          }
```

Comment: What do you expect `while (count < userinput[i])` to do?

Comment: Make your life easier and forget C-style arrays exist and use the *much 
better* C++ alternatives: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array , https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Answer (score 0):

The problem of the code is its bad indentation.

```
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    if (cin >> userinput[i])
    {
        count++;

    }   
    else
    {
        break;
    }

    while (count < userinput[i])
    {
        if (largest < userinput[i])
        {
            largest = userinput[i];
        }

        count++;                

                 }}
```

The while loop is inside the for loop. And this condition of the while loop

```
count < userinput[i]
```

does not make sense.

Separate the loops.

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++ )
{
    if (cin >> userinput[i])
    {
        count++;

    }   
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}

int largest = count == 0 ? 0 : userinput[0];

for ( size_t i = 1; i < count; i++ )
{
     if ( largest < userinput[i] )
     {
         largest = userinput[i];
     }
}
```

Take into account that you could use the standard algorithm `std::max_element` declared in the header `<algorithm>`

For example

```
auto it = std::max_element( userinput, userinput + count );

if ( it != userinput + count ) largest = *it;
```

The function `printarray` can be declared and defined like

```
std::ostream & printarray( const int array[], size_t size, std::ostream &os = std::cout )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    {
        os << array[i] << ' ';
    }

    return os;
}
```

Pay attention to that nowhere in your program the largest element is outputted.